# jQuery Object / data attribute access issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to troubleshoot some jQuery code and added this:

```
alert(this.dragEl.data('type'));
```

and all the alert returns is `undefined`.  So I try this:

```
alert(this.dragEl.html());
```

and I get the expected DOM element in the alert

```
<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-type="parent" data-id="6" data-new_record="false">
...
</li>
```

I am no JS or jQuery expert by any means and I am at a loss why I can't get the `parent` data value from this.

**UPDATE**

Did some digging to find where this is set:

```
this.dragEl = $(document.createElement(this.options.listNodeName)).addClass(this.options.listClass + ' ' + this.options.dragClass);
```

For context this is the Nestable2 (https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2) plugin.  The `li` is cloned then destroyed from the DOM.  The user is now dragging this around to drop on a new home location.  I am  trying to add some user feedback so that when you try and drop this on a 'not allowed' location the default blue placeholder dropzone div that gets added is red.  It seems to be an easy patch once I figure out how to read that data attribute on the item being moved.

Added the code in question to a JS fiddle (line 1041):

https://jsfiddle.net/jasper502/jzaqvsbp/

Comment: As an experiment try `this.dragEl.getAttribute('data-type')`

Comment: How are you setting `data-type` attribute? Is it there from page load or is it added later using jQuery?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: this.dragEl.getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: the `data-type` is from page load i.e. raw html

Comment: Added some context to the question - when you create a new element is that perhaps not a normal DOM element then?  I perhaps recall seeing something like that before.

Comment: According to the docs both `callback` and `onDragStart` pass two parameters to their functions: the first is the container and the second refers to the element. `callback: function(l,e){`. Shouldn't you be using the first argument passed to the function and not `this.dragEl`?

Comment: I tried to use the callbacks but the issue seem to be these are only called when you 'drop' the item.  I need to update as the mouse moves.  I am inside the `dragMove` function and at a point where the code is adding a moving the place holder dynamically.  I have some simple logic that can add a CSS class to the place holder.  Just need to access the data attributes of the objects in question.

Comment: I would try updating your question with the code that you are adding to the plugin's core functionality. I believe I know the problem but your code will clarify.

Comment: Added a Fiddle (Snippet was too long).  See line 1041.  Same issue with the `parent` object a few lines up.  I need to get the data attribute of that also.